# Add the button under the Rating column JQuery or AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to add the buttons after  result.date  it doesn't seem to work on my code. If I put buttons between td tags then it will show [object Object] error.

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'someUrl.php',
    data: {op : "demo"},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
            $("#restaurantList > td").empty();
            $.each(data, function(i,result){
                var buttons = $('<button/>', { id: 1, text:"Get Rating", value: "GetRating", click: function(){alert(result.business);}});
                var newRow = 
                    "<tr>"
                        +"<td>" + result.business + "</td>"
                        +"<td>" + result.address + "</td>"
                        +"<td>" + result.rating + "</td>"
                        +"<td>" + result.date + "</td>"
                    +"</tr>"                                
                    $("#restaurantList tbody").append(newRow)
                    $("#restaurantList tbody").append(buttons)
            });                     
    }
});
```

Comment: Paste the `console.log(result.business)` result here. I think it'll work if you use `result.business[i].business`

Comment: no, it will not work. You cannot append buttons to tbody.  You should create a tfoot and put them in there.

Comment: either add another column or actually put it inside the td with the date. Ignore what I said about the tfoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will append the button in a cell next to the date cell

```
 success: function(data){
        $("#restaurantList > td").empty();
        $.each(data, function(i,result){
            var buttons = $('<button/>', { id: 1, text:"Get Rating", value: "GetRating", click: function(){alert(result.business);}});
            var newRow = 
               $( "<tr>"
                    +"<td>" + result.business + "</td>"
                    +"<td>" + result.address + "</td>"
                    +"<td>" + result.rating + "</td>"
                    +"<td>" + result.date + "</td>"
                +"</tr>"  );
            var td = $("<td></td>");
            newRow.append(td);
            td.append(buttons);
            $("#restaurantList tbody").append(newRow);

        });                     
    }
```